# How to add a value to a MySQL system variable?

Tags: mysql

The MySQL system variable [sql_mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) can contain a list of comma separated [values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) or be empty.

Example:

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
```

*What is the MySQL way of adding a value to a system variable?*

Currently I am using  set `@@sql_mode = concat(@@sql_mode, ",ansi_quotes");` since I could not find a `+=` operator or similar.

Comment: You are doing it right way. More, it's not just "right" way. It's the _only_ way